# jqGrid onCellSelect Return Property from Local Data

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I've run into an issue using jqGrid 5.2.1.

I'd like to retrieve a property from a row of data when a user clicks on a cell. The property is in the original data set, but it isn't displayed in the grid. Also, I'm using the scroll feature, so the row ID's are coming back like "jqg20".

I've tried using getRowData, but that only returns the data that is displayed in that row. getLocalRow will not accept the row ID with "jqg" in it. Is there another way that I can access the same row in the local data that the user clicked in the grid to pull out a property? The property 'attr' is what I want to pull out in the example:

```
    var testData = [
                    {col1:10, col2:20, col3:30, col4:'TEST', col5:50, col6:60, col7:70, col8:80, col9:90, col10:100, attr: {property: "this is column 1"}}
]
```

Here is the jsfiddle that I've created to show the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/rhv247q7/

Comment: I can't help you with commercial Guriddo jqGrid version, but the usage of `getLocalRow` will be correct: https://jsfiddle.net/rhv247q7/4/. Additionally I'd recommend you don't use virtual scrolling (`scroll: 1`). If you have many rows, then you can use the standard paging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before to answer of the direct problems I need to do some notes.

1. It is recommend to use the jqGrid version where the problem persist. You tell us for version 5.2.1, but you use 4.6, which we think can come to some uncomfortable situations.
2. It is always good idea to set id row – this can be done either in the description of the colModel (key : true) or with the appropriate reader in this case localReader. When you set this you will be sure that there will be not a problems getting certain row and some other important commands. It is not good idea to let the grid create the ids.

Now to the problem : to do what you want you should use the getLocalRow, which return the data as it comes to the grid – i.e the original data.

In your case there was a bug when scroll is on and no id is set from the developer (i.e. the grid creates internally the id). The problem is fixed in GitHub and you can test it.